# I had a query in java script

Tags: javascript

I noticed that JavaScript's new Date() function is very smart in accepting dates in several formats.

```
Xmas95 = new Date("25 Dec, 2014 23:15:00")
Xmas95 = new Date("2015 07 12,12:52:39")
Xmas95 = new Date("08 07 2015,12:52:39")
```

I could not find documentation anywhere showing all the valid string formats while calling new Date() function.

This is for converting a string to a date. If we look at the opposite side, that is, converting a date object to a string, until now I was under the impression that JavaScript doesn't have a built-in method to format a date object into a string.

Comment: See [MDN Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) And note information "Differences in assumed time zone"

Answer (score 0):

[MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse):

> A string representing an [RFC2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14) or ISO 8601 date (other formats may be used, but results may be unexpected).